# Running SOLR 4 on a seperate application server

Tags: alfresco, solr4

What is the benefit of running SOLR 4 on a separate application server. We are in the process of evaluating our needs to upgrade to Alfresco 5.0 and I wanted to get people's opinion on the advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running SOLR on separate server you could scale it up easily as and when required. Solr bakes in replication, distribution, rebalancing and fault tolerance out of the box.So, if you have that running in seperate server you could probably even do clustering of SOLR servers to boost performence.